# Unsuccessful ndk build of my 2.6.7 Vuforia project in new Vuforia 3.0 SDK

Tags: android-ndk, cygwin, vuforia, qcar-sdk

I tried to run my ImageTargets 2.6.7 version in a new computer which runs new Vuforia SDK 3.0, android ndk 10 and all updated software according to Vuforia's Development Guide  that I installed now, but I can't build successfully my C++ libraries, having the following error in Cygwin:

Android NDK: ERROR:jni/Android.mk:QCAR-prebuilt: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file
Android NDK: Check that jni/../../../build/lib/armeabi/libVuforia.so exists  or that its path is correct
/cygdrive/c/Development/Android/android-ndk-r10c/build/core/prebuilt-library.mk:45: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.

I updated all system paths in Environment variables, I made all alterations according to this link (https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/migrating-your-android-sdk-project) in my project, but the problem still remains.

What can I do please?
Your response is really important for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the path of the libVuforia.so file is not correct. To eliminate the doubt - use a full path to the file (not `../../../`). That can be configured in your jni/Android.mk file.